# GL_TRIANGLES instead of GL_QUADS

Tags: c++, opengl

I want to modify the code for generating 3D sphere, so it uses triangles for drawing instead of quads. The problem is, as usual, that I get some error -- "vector iterator not incrementable". What's wrong with it?

```
SolidSphere(float radius, unsigned int rings, unsigned int sectors)
{
    float const R = 1.0f / (float)(rings-1);
    float const S = 1.0f / (float)(sectors-1);
    int r, s;

    vertices.resize(rings * sectors * 3);
    normals.resize(rings * sectors * 3);
    texcoords.resize(rings * sectors * 2);
    std::vector<GLfloat>::iterator v = vertices.begin();
    std::vector<GLfloat>::iterator n = normals.begin();
    std::vector<GLfloat>::iterator t = texcoords.begin();
    for(r = 0; r < rings; r++) for(s = 0; s < sectors; s++) {
            float const x = sinf(M_PI * r * R) * cosf(2 * M_PI * s * S);
            float const y = sinf(-M_PI_2 + M_PI * r * R );                
            float const z = sinf(2.0f * M_PI * s * S) * sinf( M_PI * r * R );

            *t++ = s*S;
            *t++ = r*R;

            *v++ = x * radius;
            *v++ = y * radius;
            *v++ = z * radius;

            *n++ = x;
            *n++ = y;
            *n++ = z;
    }

    indices.resize(rings * sectors * 4);
    std::vector<GLushort>::iterator i = indices.begin();
    for(r = 0; r < rings-1; r++) for(s = 0; s < sectors-1; s++) {
        /* triangles -- not working!
        *i++ = r * sectors + s;
        *i++ = (r + 1) * sectors + (s + 1);
        *i++ = r * sectors + (s + 1);

        *i++ = r * sectors + s;
        *i++ = (r + 1) * sectors + s;
        *i++ = (r + 1) * sectors + (s + 1); */

        /* quads */
        *i++ = r * sectors + s;
        *i++ = r * sectors + (s+1);
        *i++ = (r+1) * sectors + (s+1);
        *i++ = (r+1) * sectors + s;

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like your triangle-generator-version of the loop does`(sectors-1)` times `(rings-1)` iterations, each one increasing `i` six times, but you have resized the vector `i` iterates through to just `(rings * sectors * 4)`, which was enough to the quad-generator-version of the loop.

---

Assuming the triangle version was ok, this adjust shall fix it:

`indices.resize(rings * sectors * 6)`

<sub>This kind of oversight generally arises when you code without drinking enough coffee. [Or too much of it](http://bit.ly/1u1CeCQ) (graph showing the hyperbola boundaries when your code will actually fail, (mapping rings and sectors numbers to x and y) due to the fact that you are allocating more space then needed for the iterations).</sub>